# MAMP on OSX Mavericks

Tags: mamp, osx-mavericks

I installed MAMP and start running it, It is working but when I make an edit, it takes a while before it refresh and show up the change. of course I refresh page. I am sure that the php file is changed for I can see it in finder. How can I resolve this? thanks